# Finding path using algorithm A*

Tags: javascript, algorithm, a-star, gephi

hello i'd like to ask some javascript code in finding path using algorithm A*. the path will have `source node` and `target node`, and here's the example code

```
do{
    var cursor = nodes.node1 //this is source node
    for (var i in GexfJS.graph.edgeList) { // search all edgeList on graph
        var _e = GexfJS.graph.edgeList[i] //each list has variable _e
        var position = []; // where i put the pointer
        if ( _e.source == cursor ) { //when some edge source is match from the cursor(source node/initial node)
            var _n = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[_e.target]; // edge target from the node which match with the cursor
            _str += 'Found '; // just give string if it's works
            position.push(_e.target); // for pointer?
            cursor = _e.target // go to the next node, but how can i move to previos node?
            }
    }
} while(cursor!=nodes.node2); //until find the target node
```

the problem is im using `position.push` and it is array but i can't implement the pointer, if its has move next or move previous when finding path to the target node. thanks

Comment: There are many, many tutorials covering this in extreme detail - have you tried a few different sources?

Comment: You might want to use a priority queue and index it on the heuristic value + cost value. http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/class_goog_structs_PriorityQueue.html

Comment: im sry, im using javascript and im newbie in here. yes the question is how i implement the pointer for searching the path in javascript. i've been using an array, but i cant what value to insert for make some pointer

Comment: @Marty what tutorial did you mean? yes i have read for the A* algorithm on wiki, but it seems hard to implement the pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you don't need push `position.push(_e.target);` , just let the cursor in to the end , after the cursor hasn't more target , you can initial the cursor to back to the first node and don't forget each node you visit has to be set to be true

Comment: yeah i dont it before, but it seems dont work because the condition procces after the edlist have been search in the loop

Answer (score 0):

i have the answer for this, initial the cursor from the first node until the target node and don't forget each node you visit has to be set to be true if the node has visited, then go back again try to finding the first edges from the nodes, if the node hasn't true go to the next node, if the node has true find other node. here's my example code

```
pathed={};
            ketemu=false;
            cursor1="";
            if(path==true){
            while(ketemu!=true){
                var cursor = nodes.node1;
                var lala = new Array();
                var visit = new Array();
                var j = 0;
                for (var i in GexfJS.graph.edgeList) { // relasi yang dituju 
                    var _e = GexfJS.graph.edgeList[i];
                    if ( _e.source == cursor ) {
                        var _n = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[_e.target];
                        if(pathed[_n.label] != true){
                            if(_e.target==nodes.node2){

                            cursor = _e.target;
                            cursor1 = _e.target;
                            lala[j] = cursor;
                            visit[j] = cursor;
                            j++;

                            ketemu=true;
                            break;
                            }

                             if(_e.target !=nodes.node2){

                                cursor = _e.target;
                                lala[j] = cursor;
                                visit[j] = cursor;
                                j++;
                            }


                            //alert(cursor);
                            //alert(lala[j]);

                        }

                    }
                    //else if(cursor1==_e.target){
                    //cursor = nodes.node1;
                    //alert(cursor);
                    //}


                }
                if(ketemu!=true){
                i=0;
                for(var j=lala.length-1;j>=0;j--){
                var test = lala.length-1;
                var ujung = lala[test];
                var koyong = nodes.node1;

                i++;

                }

                ujung = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[ujung];
                pathed[ujung.label] = true;
                cursor = koyong;

                }

            }

                for(var k=0;k<visit.length;k++){
                var visitednya = visit[k];
                var _n = GexfJS.graph.nodeList[visitednya];
                _str += '<li><div class="smallpill" style="background: ' + _n.color.base +'"></div><a href="#" onmouseover="GexfJS.params.activeNode = ' + _e.source + '" onclick="displayNode(' + _e.source + ', true); return false;">' + _n.label + '</a>' + ( GexfJS.params.showEdgeWeight && _e.weight ? ' [' + _e.weight + ']' : '') + '</li>';
                }
                visit=[];



            //end
            }
```

thanks